# An image filled with circles

Tags: language

Here is an image. My question is simple: *what is this?* (As a side note, I did not invent this, and it was not intended by its creator to be a puzzle.)

> [image: first image]

PS: If you believe you have solved it, see if you can figure out [this second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIOj6.jpg).

Comment: A meta-puzzle: Can you figure out why this was invented?

Comment: (also, can anyone help me think of a better title for this post?)

Comment: Please dont post the answer with the question? Because the main idea of puzzling.se is to solve the puzzles given by others.

Comment: @VarunW. Huh? I didn't post the answer.

Comment: So [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIOj6.jpg) is not the answer?

Comment: @VarunW. That is not the answer; it is a second puzzle.

Comment: Then could you please post it as a separate puzzle if they dont have a connection?

Comment: @VarunW. They are not disconnected, either. I think you will understand the connection once you solve the puzzle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe not the final answer, but:

> There are 26 symbol packs (a few of them solo symbols), as many as in our alphabet.
>  So I assume each of them stands for a letter.
> Some of the circles are there multiple times and there is a system behind it.
> For example the ones I noticed first:

- > the two circles that could mean 'u' are also the last two circles of
  > 'w' (double-u).
- > the 5th circle, the 'e', is the second symbol on many letters,
  > that are spoken with an e, like d,t,p ('de, te, pe') but it doesn't appear on for
  > example l, m, n.

So - *what is this?*

> I think it's kind of a cipher for the english alphabet, that depicts how the letters are actually spoken. Like you would write ae, be, ce...til zed. I had a theory that - as the circles remind me of emojis/faces - it has to do with how you move your mouth or lips, but the second image kind of destroyed that idea, as I can't remember to ever make the first or third symbol with my mouth :) Nevertheless, they proved me right in the alphabet idea, because here you see the numbers one to ten.
> Two is 't' and 'u', seven is 's', 'a', 'v' and 'n'. Some symbols are new, because they're not included in the alphabet like 'th' in three.

Comment: Correct! (And it _is_ meant to be how you move your lips. The first character in the second image is lips pursed for a 'w' sound. the third character in the second image is arguably the worst symbol in the set; it has the same mouth shape as the 't' and 'd', but it also has a line representing the nose and a star representing abstractly 'this one involves the nose', signifying a nasal sound like 'n'. Re: 7, carefully note the distinction between the 'eh' and 'ah' symbols.) The symbols were developed to teach Deaf children how to articulate speech.

Comment: Oh that's a really cool thing. I can see how it fits for most of the letters, just got distracted. Thank you for teaching me something new :)